# How to replace image by it's comments in Android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a social media app and in that I want that when a user swipes over the post the image of the post should be replaced by comments.
Suggest some way to do this
I am using recycler view for showing posts

Comment: Can you add an image of the view?

Comment: @SharatChandra sorry bro but I don't have the layout file of this as I am unable to achieve it by myself so I deleted my project and now started as fresh